# App not searchable by name at certain Geo Location

Tags: android, google-play

We recently (1 week ago) published an app on the google play store. At first we wanted to publish only in Ethiopia and turns out Ethiopia is not in the list available countries. After trying to publish only in `Rest Of World`, the app store was telling me that we couldn't publish because we didn't select any country.

We then decided to publish in every country plus `Rest Of World` and it worked perfectly. However, the app is searchable by name in lot of different countries.

Searching:

- US: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Saquama&c=apps&gl=us
- France: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Saquama&c=apps&gl=fr
- Kenya: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=saquama&c=apps&gl=ke
- ...

Returns the app as the first result.

However Searching https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Saquama&c=apps&gl=et, with ["et" being Ethiopia's country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_codes:_D%E2%80%93E#_Ethiopia) doesn't work. And it's not like it appears at the end of the list (which would be [ASO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_store_optimization#:%7E:text=From%20Wikipedia%2C%20the%20free%20encyclopedia%20App%20store%20optimization,with%20the%20objective%20of%20increasing%20organic%20app%20downloads.) problem), It doesn't even appear in the result.

Any idea why? Is it something we can do anything about or we can only wait?

### More details

- our app is free (so [available](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10532353?hl=en) in `Rest Of World`)
- our AndroidManifest doesn't involve hardware related features (so app [shouldn't be filtered out](https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters))
- minSDK is 21 (pretty low and some people with newer phones still can't find it)
- targetSDK is 30
- here are the permissions in AndroidManifest (don't know if it's relevant):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was not about indexing, neither about ASO but about the fact that Google Play [open testing](https://play.google.com/console/about/opentesting/) is apparently not available in Ethiopia (there is no documentation mentioning it though).

So if you are working with `Rest Of World` region be aware that your app my not be available due to that.

Comment: the links you've provided are not for open testing!! So I think it is not an open testing issue, and it is only needed some time.

Comment: they were, now the app is in production that's why it doesn't appear as early access.

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting a few more days, until then, send your potential users direct links.

For the app to appear in search results requires some time, plus, my guess is, it depends on internal Google algorithms. Also, store presence update times differ between store web page and Google Play Android app, too.